# How can I exclude stubbing from invocation count?

Tags: mockito

Say, I have the following class.

```java
class User {

    Integer getAge() {};

    void setAge(Integer age) {};

    String getAgeAsString() {
        return ofNullabe(getAge()).map(Object::toString).orElse(null);
    }

    void setAgeAsString(String ageAsString) {
        setAge(ofNullable(ageAsString).map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(null));
    }
}
```

Verifying the `getAgeAsString` method is straightforward.

```java
@Test
void __() {
    var instance = spy(new User());
    given(instance.getAge()).willReturn(0); // seems count
    var result = instance.getAgeAsString();
    verify(instance, times(1)).getAge();     // expects 2 times, not 1
}
```

I'm currently clearing the invocation just after the stubbing.

```java
@Test
void __() {
    var instance = spy(new User());
    given(instance.getAge()).willReturn(0);
    clearInvocation(instance);              // <<<<<
    var result = instance.getAgeAsString();
    verify(instance, times(1)).getAge();     // works now
}
```

Is there any nice way to exclude stubbing code from the invocation count?

Or is this normal?

Comment: Why would you want to know if `getAge()` was called? That seems like an implementation detail that you shouldn't be testing in the first place.